# Rewrite http to https on Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

I try to rewrite `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`

I read some answer about this, and it's working when i try it on my local server.
I do it with these lines :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
    [...]
}
```

But when i came from an other computer with the ip like this : `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8086` it redirect me at `https://localhost` and I don't want that.

So, i try like this :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
    [...]
}
```

Another problem : it redirect me at `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` without my :8086 ! That's not what I want too...

Anyone have a solution for me ?

Thanks a lot !

Maxime.

Edit :

My config :

```
server {


    listen 80;


    #rewrite ^(.*) https://$host:8086$request_uri permanent;

    root /var/www;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {


    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      ./cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ./cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

On my rooter's config, the port redirection for this server is 8086.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect http onto https on the same port. They must listen on different ports, or you will just get a rewrite loop.

So for example:

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /nowhere; # this doesn't have to be a valid path since we are redirecting, you don't have to change it.
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name example.com;
     root /some/valid/directory;

     ssl on;
}
```

---

**Edit for full configuration:**

Just to clarify that you want:

```
        World
          |
          |
http://localhost:8086
          |
          |
https://localhost:8086
          |
          |
https://localhost:443
```

You will need to use proxy_pass for this. Also nginx error code 497 might help: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors

Add the following server directive to your configuration...

```
server { 
    listen 8086 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      ./cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ./cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:443;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already do that. But it redirect me wrong :/ the :8086 is not here again !

Comment: @maxouhell, :8086 should not be redirected at all. Only port 80... Can you copy and paste from your config?

Comment: I've been do it on my first post. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Maxouhell, Modified my answer. Using nginx internal error code 497 to redirect seems to be the answer instead of a rewrite rule.

Comment: Ok, i will try somethink like that. Bvut that not exactly what i want to do : **world**-->xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8086-->`https://localhost`<--`http://localhost`<--**me on my local server** sorry, i'm not very understandable :/

Comment: That's fair enough, just have a simple rewrite rule for port 80 that I showed above! `rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;`